# Is there a PHP calculation which could result in a -0?

Tags: php, casting

I am having trouble with a complex script which sometimes (About 2 or 3 times while calulating about 90'000 values), generates a '-0' and writes it into the database. I suspect it's a string (The values which are calulated can result in integers, floats or strings.)*

Is there any PHP calculation which might result in a '-0'?

* = Oh, how I miss strong typing sometimes...

Comment: Also, is the DB all varchars?

Comment: Are the result numbers rounded?

Comment: +0 and -0 are different bit patterns in IEEE-754 floating point. For twos-complement integers, they are identical.  That might narrow down the source of the "-0".

Comment: to check if the result is really -0, try changing your field type to int (that is if your field type is not int, but if it is, WOW!).

Comment: Like I said: The values can be either strings (Actual letters), integers or floats. This prevents me from rounding or strong typing in the database (Where I store the values in varchars, yes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rounding a negative number toward positive infinity, as `ceil()` does, can produce -0.

```
echo ceil(-.7);

// -0
```

The same result comes with, e.g., `round(-.2)`.

Both of these will resolve to true:

```
(-0 == 0)
(ceil(-.7) == 0)
```

While these will resolve to true and false, respectively:

```
(-0 === 0)
(ceil(-.7) === 0)
```

Edit: An interesting (and implemented) rfc can be read [here](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/rounding).

Comment: Thanks, I think the culprit was the round()-method which is being applied to some of my values.

Answer (score 5):

As Gurdas says, you can have your strong typing in the database. That aside, I don't know the answer to your question but I know how would I approach the problem.

The problem, as I understand it, is that you don't know in which cases you get the '-0', which is a valid [floating point representation of 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), by the way. So you have to find in which cases you are getting that. I'd take one of two routes:

1. Use [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), raise an error in the database insertion code when the value is '-0' to get a stack_trace with arguments (use xdebug.collect_params=1)
2. Create an empty string at the beginning of the script, populating it with all the operations and operands being done as they are, with the result and line. Afterwards, in the insertion clause add an if ($value == '-0') { print $string; }